# Can't run npm run build on windows 7

Tags: windows, npm

the command npm run build fails on windows 7. I traced the cause to one incompatibility. The issue is in the line:

```
"copy": "cp src/{*.html,*.css,*.js} built/"
```

which produces the following error:

npm ERR! Failed at the ng2-test-seed@0.0.2 copy script 'cp src/{index.html,style
s.css,system-config.js} built/'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ng2-test-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.

My package.json code is given below

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install --ambient",
    "clean": "rimraf built/",
    "copy": "cp src/{index.html,styles.css,system-config.js} built/",
    "copytemplates": "cp src/app/{*.html,*.css} built/app/",
    "build": "tsc && npm run copy && npm run copytemplates",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "http-server -p 9090 -c-1",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
```